# Get error(115) trying to mount a Windows filesystem from Ubuntu

Tags: networking, mount

- Ubuntu 14.04LTS server, I have no GUI desktop
- In my example I'll use a fake IP address.
- Trying to mount from Ubuntu to \1.2.3.4\users\me\subdir. Someone has to put a spreadsheet file on the \1.2.3.4\users\me\subdir and my program on Ubuntu has to read it.
- I can ping 1.2.3.4 just fine, so it can't be a firewall issue, right?

I have read about 12 pages from my goole search, a few from this forum but I have nothing that works yet. This is what I did.

```
sudo mount -t cifs '\\1.2.3.4/users/shared/chuck/subdir' /home/comp/mnt/subdir -o username=chuck,password=CR4gilson 
mount error(115): Operation now in progress
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

This message is in /var/log/syslog:

```
Feb 15 09:43:56 ubuntucomp kernel: [7519048.289580] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
Feb 15 09:43:56 ubuntucomp kernel: [7519048.289872] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -115
```

In my ufw output samba seems to be allowed anywhere:

```
Samba                      ALLOW       Anywhere
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try `telnet 1.2.3.4 445` 
the expected result is:

```
$ telnet 1.2.3.4 445
Trying 1.2.3.4...
Connected to 1.2.3.4.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

if not - you have a problem with the firewall.